# SystemStackError (stack level too deep) - rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

building with Rails API. Getting the error `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)` when submitting an API request to login.

The error is around rendering JSON on this line `render json: {user: @user, token: token}.as_json, serializer: nil, :status => :ok`

Tried solutions:

[SystemStackError (stack level too deep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517848/systemstackerror-stack-level-too-deep)

[Ruby 2.4 and Rails 4 stack level too deep (SystemStackError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504106/ruby-2-4-and-rails-4-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror)

https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/2214

The users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  #auth_login only action to be authorized before an action
  before_action :authenticate_request, only: [:auto_login, :edit]

  def login
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      token = encode_token({email: @user.email})
      render json: {user: @user, token: token}.as_json, serializer: nil, :status => :ok
    else
      render json: {error: "Invalid email or password"}, :status => :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def default_serializer_options
    {
    serializer: nil
    }
  end
end
```

The error is annoying as it's inconsistent! Sometimes it builds with no issue and sometimes it doesn't. Not sure where to go with this as I don't see anywhere where code is recursive.

Update: Application Controller with `encode_token`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    before_action :authenticate_request

    def encode_token(payload)
        JWT.encode(payload, 's3cr3t')
    end

    def auth_header
        #requesting the header type of authorization (with token) that we will declare through our api requests
        # { Authorization: 'Bearer <token>' }
        request.headers['Authorization']
    end

    def decoded_token
        if auth_header
            #going to take the token and decode it
            token = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
            # header: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>' }
            begin
                puts token
                JWT.decode(token, 's3cr3t') #The header is sending the correct token but returning a fail.
            rescue JWT::DecodeError
                # puts "fail"
                nil
            end
        end
    end

    def logged_in_user
        #consults decode_token to check the header for valid information
        if decoded_token
            puts "Do"
            email = decoded_token[0]['email']
            @user = User.find_by(email: email)
        end
    end

    def logged_in?
        #returns true or false
        !!logged_in_user
    end

    def authenticate_request
        #consults logged_in? see see if user is authorized
        render json: { message: 'Please log in' }, status: :unauthorized unless logged_in?
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please add code for encode_token here?

Comment: @RishiPithadiya yep, added!

Answer (score -1):

For the solution, I found that it was an issue with rendering the @user. Although I had reset the db through `rake db:reset` and more, I needed to reset postgres. After, all worked as intended.